# How to keep Apps, that are banned from the offical market, up to date?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates

Sadly, a few fine Apps are banned from the official Market by Google (e.g. [Transdroid](http://www.transdroid.org/)): How can I keep those Apps up to date, without visiting the project sites regularly?

Answer (score 2):

I usually sign up for an RSS feed on the project's website, and add the feed to a separate group in Google Reader.  Since I sync up with Reader twice a day, when an update to an app I'm following is available I know about it the same day.

For sites that don't provide a native RSS feed, there are some services that can generate an RSS feed on-the-fly, like [Feed43](http://feed43.com/) or [FeedBeater](http://www.diffbot.com/apps/feedbeater/), for example.