# Is there a way see if any of the apps on my phone have updates available?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates

Is there a way see if any of the apps on my phone have updates available?

I occasionally get a notification that updates are available but is there a way of checking manually?

If I clear the notification area is there a way to see what apps had updates available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the "Play Store", hit the context menu button and select "My Apps". This will show the list of installed Apps on the device and possible updates for the Apps.

See [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18891/how-to-keep-apps-that-are-banned-from-the-offical-market-up-to-date), ff you have Apps that weren't installed with the Play Store

Comment: FYI, it may take a minute or two to check the update list, especially if you're not on wifi.

Comment: Of course, this assumes that all of your apps are installed via the Play Store. If you sideload apps or use an alternative market this may not apply.

Comment: For sideloaded apps see this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18891/how-to-keep-apps-that-are-banned-from-the-offical-market-up-to-date